# Batch File to silently auto-install Forge

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, minecraft-forge

I am writing a batch file to install forge (for modded Minecraft). And I can not figure out a way to auto-install Forge. I can't find anything online nor have adding "/s" to the file done anything.

The exact code I have now is

```
cls
@echo OFF
echo Installing Forge for Minecraft
echo Click "OK" with "Install client" selected
timeout 10
forge-1.16.5-36.2.34-installer.jar
pause
```

Because I tried using

```
cls
@echo off
echo Installing Forge for Minecraft
forge-1.16.5-36.2.34-installer.jar /s
pause
```

(The "pause" is only there because I don't want the prompt closing before I can see want happens)
Which didn't work instead just opening the forge installer.

Ideally I would like something like the second code block but the forge install doesn't open and need interaction (and also output the installer logs into the console)

Comment: In a regular Minecraft Forge installation, is there any need for user interaction? That is to say, are there any confirmations needed, choosing of a directory, type of installation, confirming / closing the dialog once the installation completes etc?

Comment: I was under the impression that there are no silent installation options for their installer, so that the end user can view the advertising.

Comment: @FiddlingAway There is interaction with type (client, server, or an option to just extract). And changing the dir but it has a default one. And it does have a "Forge has been install" box that pops ups.

Comment: @Compo I have looked to see if there is an option but I am always brought back here (either to my own question or to someone saying something about the ads on the website). I am still unsure whether such option exists. But for the end user seeing the ads it doesn't matter because the installer is already in the folder downloaded (the only option to my knowledge to get the end user to see the ads is to open the site in their browser and have them manually download it)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly related to Minecraft but in general to batch and silent/automatic operations. Your batch script lacks an assigned program. It's not recommended to do so, because in your example the `.jar` file will use the program it might be chosen as default by player (here probably Java). Imagine there isn't a default program, then start the batch would only lead to prompt for chose standard program.

Long story short:
Have you tried command structure like these?

```
java -jar forge-1.16.5-36.2.34-installer.jar /s
```

or

```
[AppThatInstallsJavaSilent].exe forge-1.16.5-36.2.34-installer.jar
```

Comment: If I am understanding you currently then some code lines up already fix this issue. For the moment how the install works (or ideally works) is it asks whether the user would like to install the modpack or add new mods to the already existing mod folder then with install modpack selected it first checks to see if Java is install if not installs it then proceeds to installing Forge then moving the mods to \.minecraft dir.

Comment: Glad, if I could help. I'm not familiar with Java or Minecraft mods, so I can't tell which parameters you should use at best. If you have read my answer attentively, the player file (exe) was missing - specifiy "java" or "java.exe" at the beginning approach the Java program.
For Java, here is a link to a website with possible command line parameters:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html